# Determine the integers $a$ such that the congruence $ax^4 \equiv b \pmod{13}$ has a solution for $b = 2, 5, 6$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine the integers $a$ such that the congruence $ax^4 \equiv b \pmod{13}$ 
has a solution for $b = 2, 5, 6$

---

I think the problem wants $a$'s that work for all $b=2,5,6$. Can I please have a hint on how to approach this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: For any integer $x, (x^4 \bmod 13) \in \{0,1,3,9\}$

Comment: Thank you :) let me see if I can take it home from here xD

Comment: would a=2,5,6 work ?

Comment: they are working thanks a lot !

Comment: yes; more generally, $a \equiv \{2,5,6\} \bmod 13$ works. So $a=15$ is Ok too.

Comment: The notation is wrong. You could correct it by changing the set to $\{0+13k, 1+13l, 3+13m, 9+13n\}, k,l,m,n\in\mathbb Z$ or by changing $x^4\mod 13$ to $x^4 \%13$.

Comment: @user314 - it was only a hint... but I updated a little anyway :-)

Comment: @Joffan But you changed nothing. You're implying that we could write $2^4 \mod {13} = 3$, while it must be $2^4\mod 13 = 3\mod {13}$ or $2^4\equiv 3\pmod{13}$. In addition to what I suggested above in the other comment, you could also write $\{0\mod 13, 1\mod 13, 3\mod 13, 9\mod 13\}$.

Comment: @user314 if you see any room for someone misunderstanding my meaning I will update further, but otherwise, I'm going to leave it. Thanks for your suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The nonzero $4$-th powers in $\mathbf 13$ are $\{1, 3, -4\}$ as @Joffan noticed. Let $c$ be one of these values. We have to solve the equation with unknown $a$: $\enspace a=c^{-1}b$.

Now, an inverse of a $4$-th power is again a $4$-th power and  the set of $c^{-1}$ is just  $\{1,3,-4\}$. When we compute all possible values for $c^{-1}b$, we simply find
$$a\in\{2,5,6\} \mod 13.$$